# Applying same formatting to a subset of buttons?

Tags: swift

There are several buttons in my project that are formatted the same. What's the best way to apply the same formatting to multiple buttons so I don't have to do it manually each time?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What does *formatting* mean?

Comment: Create a class with a static function.

Comment: @vadian I meant formatting as in the button's characteristics (ex. color, border, font, size). Maybe "style" is a better description for it?

Comment: Create a subclass.

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using an extension on UIButton in combination with a factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass UIButton and use that instead.

Here's some sample code for the UIButton subclass and for creating two new buttons programatically. If you're using the storyboard, add a UIButton to your view and then change its class to your custom subclass in the Identity Inspector.

[image: UIButton subclass]

The UIButton subclass:

```
class OneButtonToRuleThemAll: UIButton {
    // This is used when you create your view programatically.
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    // This is used when the view is created from a storyboard or a Nib file.
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    // This is optional.
    // You can use it to initialize your view programatically with specific parameters.
    convenience init(frame: CGRect, title: String) {
        self.init(frame: frame)
        setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    }

    // Do your custom configuration here
    func commonInit() {
        clipsToBounds = true
        let backgroundImage = UIImage(from: .green)
        setBackgroundImage(backgroundImage, for: .normal)
        setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
    }

    // You may need to perform some of your configurations outsite the initializers.
    // You can use other methods from the UIView lifecycle for this.
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = frame.height/2
    }
}
```

This is not essential to this answer but if you want to change your button's background, you should use a UIImage instead of setting background color, in order to make use of the highlight effects. This extension can be used to create an image from a UIColor:

```
extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(from color: UIColor, size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) {
        let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        guard let cgImage = image?.cgImage else { return nil }
        self.init(cgImage: cgImage)
    }
}
```

Creating two buttons programatically:

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonsStackView: UIStackView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Using the designated initializer
    let button = OneButtonToRuleThemAll(frame: CGRect.zero)
    button.setTitle("Button From Code", for: .normal)
    buttonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)

    // Using the convenience initializer
    let button2 = OneButtonToRuleThemAll(frame: CGRect.zero, title: "But Wait, There's More!")
    buttonsStackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
}
```

Comment: Using `backgroundColor` in a button means that you won't have any highlighting effects, which is the core point of a button. Generally a bad idea. Use a background image, even generated dynamically from a color. Also, making such components `@IBDesignable` would be probably a good idea, to preview them in IB.

Comment: You're right, thanks. Those were more or less random examples of possible customizations. But they may as well be good ones. I'm going to edit the answer to reflect your suggestion. As for the @IBDesignable, I remember creating a few in the past and also importing code that used them, but IB always became unbearably slow. But they're definitely nice. Was I doing something wrong perhaps? Has this improved with recent versions of Xcode?

Comment: Marking this as the best answer. Thanks @Peter for the detailed response with examples included. Appreciate the help everyone!